# Can't figure out what's wrong with my solution to an indefinite integral

Tags: proof-verification, indefinite-integrals

I tried integrating $\int{\frac{xdx}{(Ax + B)^n}}$, and my solution was
$$
\int{\frac{xdx}{(Ax + B)^n}} = \frac{1}{A^2}\left[\frac{(Ax + B)^{-n}}{-n} - B\frac{(Ax + B)^{-n + 1}}{-n + 1}\right] + c
$$
which I got by substituting $u = Ax + B$ and then integrating $\frac{1}{A^2}\int{\frac{u-B}{u^n}du} = 1/A^2(\int{\frac{du}{u^{n-1}}} - B\int{\frac{du}{u^n}})$. WolframAlpha gives me a [different answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20of%20x%2F%28Ax%20%2B%20B%29%5En), and I can't determine if the two answers are equivalent (which it doesn't look like they are). Is my answer the same as WolframAlpha's answer? And what algorithm or procedure might WolframAlpha have used to get a solution to this integral?

**EDIT:** Okay maybe I should post my solution, so that people get an idea of my thought process.

$$
\begin{align}
\int{\frac{xdx}{(Ax + B)^n}} & = \int{\frac{1/A(u - B)}{u^n}\cdot\frac{1}{A}du}, \ u = Ax + B \\
& = \frac{1}{A^2}\left(\int{\frac{udu}{u^n}} - B\int{\frac{du}{u^n}}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{A^2}\left(\int{\frac{du}{u^{n-1}}} - B\int{\frac{du}{u^n}}\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{A^2}\left(\frac{u^{-n}}{-n} - B\frac{u^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\right) + c \\
& = \frac{1}{A^2}\left(\frac{(Ax + B)^{-n}}{-n} - B\frac{(Ax + B)^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\right) + c
\end{align}
$$

It seems alright to me, but I don't see how
$$
\frac{1}{A^2}\left(\frac{(Ax + B)^{-n}}{-n} - B\frac{(Ax + B)^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\right) = -\frac{(Ax + B)^{-n+1}(A(n-1)x+B)}{A^2(n-2)(n-1)}
$$
where the right hand side is what WolframAlpha is giving. **So are the two expressions equivalent?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step between the two following lines is wrong:

$$\frac{1}{A^2}\left(\int{\frac{du}{u^{n-1}}} - B\int{\frac{du}{u^n}}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{A^2}\left(\frac{u^{-n}}{-n} - B\frac{u^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\right) + c$$

Actually, $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{u^{n-1}}=u^{-n+1}}$, so when you integrate, you get $\displaystyle{\frac{u^{-n+2}}{-n+2}}$, not $\displaystyle{\frac{u^{-n}}{-n}}$.

Comment: Oh are you serious? I can't believe I missed that, thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{A^2}\left(\frac{(Ax+B)^{-n}}{-n}-B\frac{(Ax+B)^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{A^2}\left(\frac{(Ax+B)^{-n+1}}{-n(Ax + B)}-B\frac{(Ax+B)^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{(Ax+B)^{-n+1}}{A^2}\left(\frac{1}{-n(Ax + B)}-\frac{B}{-n+1}\right)\\
&=-\frac{(Ax+B)^{-n+1}}{A^2}\left(\frac{1}{n(Ax + B)}-\frac{B}{n-1}\right)\\
&=-\frac{(Ax+B)^{-n+1}}{A^2}\frac{n-1-Bn(Ax+B)}{n(n-1)(Ax + B)}\\
&=-\frac{(Ax+B)^{-n}}{A^2}\frac{n-1-Bn(Ax+B)}{n(n-1))}\\
&\neq-\frac{(Ax + B)^{-n+1}(A(n-1)x+B)}{A^2(n-2)(n-1)}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the same as what I did to get my answer, and darya khosrotash got a similar answer to mine (except for a factor of $A$ that I missed). So this is the same as what WA says? I must be missing something because I don't see how mine or darya khosrotash's answers are the same as what was given by the computer.

Answer (score -1):

$$\int \frac{x}{(ax+b)^n}dx=\\\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{ax}{(ax+b)^n}dx =\\\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{ax+b-b}{(ax+b)^n}dx =\\\frac{1}{a}\int (\frac{ax+b}{(ax+b)^n}dx +\frac{-b}{(ax+b)^n}dx)=\\\frac{1}{a}\int (\frac{1}{(ax+b)^{n-1}}dx +\frac{-b}{(ax+b)^n}dx)=\\\frac{1}{a}\int ((ax+b)^{-(n-1)}dx -b(ax+b)^{-n}dx)=\\\frac{1}{a}(\frac{(ax+b)^{-(n-1)+1}}{(-(n-1)+1)a}  -b \frac{(ax+b)^{-(n)+1}}{(-(n)+1)a})=\\\frac{1}{a}(\frac{(ax+b)^{-(n-1)+1}}{(-(n-1)+1)a}  -ab \frac{(ax+b)^{-(n)+1}}{(-(n)+1)a^2})=\\now\\factor\\\frac{1}{a^2}\\\frac{1}{a^2}(\frac{(ax+b)^{-(n-1)+1}}{(-(n-1)+1)}  -ab \frac{(ax+b)^{-(n)+1}}{(-(n)+1)})
$$

Comment: Yah! Except for that factor of $a$ on the second term in the final line, that's essentially what I got! How is it the same as what WA says?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question...